# Convert TimeSpan to Double

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I'm having some trouble with convertion of timespan to double. That's the code I used to convert double value to timespan:

```
int r = 150;
string t = TimeSpan.FromHours(Convert.ToDouble(r)).ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss");
```

It gives:

> t--> 6.06:00:00

Now I need to retrieve the value (`150`) from timespan (`6.06:00:00`).

Comment: How do you assign `ToString()` to `Timespan t`?

Comment: Someone edited the post and 'corrected' the code from `Timespan` to `string` when they shouldn't have.  It makes the comments nonsensical now.

Answer (score 5):

You need the total-hours for a given timespan?

```
double totalHours = t.TotalHours;
```

So don't convert the timespan to a string but store it as a `TimeSpan`.

[`TimeSpan.TotalHours`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Gets the value of the current TimeSpan structure expressed in whole
>   and fractional hours.

If you have a string `6.06:00:00` and you want the number of hours, parse it first to `TimeSpan`:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse("6.06:00:00");
double hours = ts.TotalHours;
```